# Why is my texture getting distorted in render view?

Tags: texturing

[image: texture view]

[image: render view]

I don't understand why my texture is getting distorted and some parts are missing or just super flat.

Comment: Hello maybe pack your images and share your object?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgaplwfgSzN-mPUAzGciKS2foUldzg?e=JoVo0l

Comment: onedrive link to the blend file

Comment: your link doesn'twork   :(((

Comment: It worked for me... try this one: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgaplwfgSzN-mPUJs7LKT70TBQfgAw?e=K1Oqr9

Comment: wow aha the material is super complicated   ^^

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW-DrBQ-u1o&ab_channel=Erindale

Comment: How close is your node tree supposed to be to Erindales' one? - His was done in Blender 2.90 so some of the nodes are going to be a bit different now, but yours is certainly not the same as his one. It's going to take a lot of work for anyone here to compare them and see what the difference is! :^(

Comment: I left image texture group nodes but otherwise I tried to be as throughout as possible. I'm assuming I left some nodes uncoccencted or connected them wrong and that is causing the issue.

Comment: In that case you're going to have to go right through it again and see where you went wrong. We're certainly not going to do it for you!

Comment: Try to Apply the scale before texturing. Your model have 0.5 0.2 0.5 scale.

Comment: I figured it might have been because of unapplied modifiers!